# How to open link in other browser?

Tags: html, hyperlink

How to open link in  other browser? For example:

```
<a href="sample.html" >click to open in firefox</a>
<a href="sample.html" >click to open in Safari</a>
<a href="sample.html" >click to open in IE</a>
<a href="sample.html" >click to open in Chrome</a>
```

Is it possible?

Any ideas or suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cool question. With simple html, I do not think it's possible.

If you are looking to test application, you could write OS specific utility.

Comment: Correct. You need to have additional software installed on the client side (a plug-in or activex) to enable the client browser to launch the browser of your choice.

Comment: But the additional software could be Java, for example and the logic could be implemented in a signed Applet.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

Its strictly a user preference to open web pages in a browser of his choice. You won't be able to control that and better never try to do that.

If you are doing this test your web site in different browsers then take a look at **[browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/)**

Comment: I don't think it's always strictly a user preference, it depends on the audience. I work at a place were some users don't know what a browser is, it's not their preference, it's just that they think the "e" icon is the Internet.